# render a view within a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I render a view within another view... in rails... is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use view partials

See section 3.4 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: Linking to a massive reference page isn't very helpful.  Better to provide some working code.

Answer (score 20):

```
#hotdog_controller
def show
  # by default renders template hotdog/show.html.erb
end

#hotdog/show.html.erb
<%= render :template => 'ketchup' -%>
```

Answer (score 1):

A complete view inside another a view?  Normally the way you would handle something like this in rails would be with partials.

Create a set of shared partials, and then just render them in each of the views.

Answer (score 0):

I do the same thing a few times, but I load the sub views in through AJAX. And that AJAX is instantiated within the partial.